# Convert Json array in text file to CSV using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert an array stored in a text file to CSV format. I'm getting an error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" I'm assuming the error is due to an incorrect Json structure? How can I work around this?

Python:

```
import csv
import json

with open("c://JsonData/File.txt") as x:
    data = json.dumps(x.read())

x = data
f = csv.writer(open("Export.csv", "w", newline=''))
f.writerow(["firstName", "lastName", "phoneNum", "city", "state", "zip"])

for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["Employee"]["firstName"],
                x["Employee"]["lastName"],
                x["Employee"]["phoneNum"],
                x["Employee"]["city"],
                x["Employee"]["state"],
                x["Employee"]["zip"])
```

Array in text file:

```
{
"Employee":             
[ {
      "firstName" : "Sam",
      "lastName" : "Tucker",
      "phoneNum" : "555-6789",
      "city" : "Mayberry",
      "state" : "NC",
      "zip" : "35083",
    }, {
      "firstName" : "Johny Paul",
      "lastName" : "Jason",
      "phoneNum" : "555-6769",
      "city" : "Mayberry",
      "state" : "NC",
      "zip" : "35083",
    }, {
      "firstName" : "Rafe",
      "lastName" : "Holister",
      "phoneNum" : "555-6489",
      "city" : "Mayberry",
      "state" : "NC",
      "zip" : "35083",",
    } ]
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["firstName"],
                x["lastName"],
                x["phoneNum"],
                x["city"],
                x["state"],
                x["zip"])
```

With the array formatted like this:

```
[ {
      "firstName" : "Sam",
      "lastName" : "Tucker",
      "phoneNum" : "555-6789",
      "city" : "Mayberry",
      "state" : "NC",
      "zip" : "35083",
    }, {
      "firstName" : "Johny Paul",
      "lastName" : "Jason",
      "phoneNum" : "555-6769",
      "city" : "Mayberry",
      "state" : "NC",
      "zip" : "35083",
    }, {
      "firstName" : "Rafe",
      "lastName" : "Holister",
      "phoneNum" : "555-6489",
      "city" : "Mayberry",
      "state" : "NC",
      "zip" : "35083",",
    } ]
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: What is `for x in x:` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: What issue(s) did you have with what you "also tried"?

Comment: Please [edit] to include the error traceback. Probably try to reduce this to a [mre].

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm piecing together examples from others but figured it was related to Invalid JSON. What's missing in the JSON? I get the same error using both examples. Also a newbie to Python but guess I could have used ```for data in data``` instead of the x variable to cut down on confusion.

Comment: What would 'for data in data:` accomplish?

Comment: as a general suggestion and in order to not confuse others or yourself I strongly suggest to **not** write things like  `for  in x`, bot more something like `for row in mylist:` or `for entry in data:` using naming the iterator variable with the same name than the object to iterate through might render the code less intuitive to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import csv
import json

with open("data.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

with open("data.csv", "w") as file:
    file = csv.writer(file)
    file.writerow(["firstName","lastName","phoneNum","city","state","zip"])

    for d in data:
        file.writerow([d["firstName"],d["lastName"],d["phoneNum"],
                       d["city"],d["state"],d["zip"]])
```

When applied on the following JSON file "data.json"

```
[ {
      "firstName" : "Sam",
      "lastName" : "Tucker",
      "phoneNum" : "555-6789",
      "city" : "Mayberry",
      "state" : "NC",
      "zip" : "35083"
    }, {
      "firstName" : "Johny Paul",
      "lastName" : "Jason",
      "phoneNum" : "555-6769",
      "city" : "Mayberry",
      "state" : "NC",
      "zip" : "35083"
    }, {
      "firstName" : "Rafe",
      "lastName" : "Holister",
      "phoneNum" : "555-6489",
      "city" : "Mayberry",
      "state" : "NC",
      "zip" : "35083"
    }
]
```

it generates the following CSV file "data.csv" :

```
firstName,lastName,phoneNum,city,state,zip
Sam,Tucker,555-6789,Mayberry,NC,35083
Johny Paul,Jason,555-6769,Mayberry,NC,35083
Rafe,Holister,555-6489,Mayberry,NC,35083
```